# Click On The Google Form Quiz ViewScore Button Using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have tried to click this last button to see score using Selenium but it doesnt work. I tried using CSSselector. Any ideas what will work lol?

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ90V.png

```
try
        {
            var reee = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.freebirdFormviewerViewFormContentWrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div.freebirdFormviewerViewFormCard.exportFormCard > div > div.freebirdFormviewerViewResponseLinksContainer > div > a > span"));
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(reee);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            actions.Click();
            actions.Build().Perform();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("well not working");
        }
```

(It works for Submit Button btw)
(Go easy on me I'm 15)

Comment: can you show the html markup for button?

Comment: `<span jsslot="" class="appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonContent exportButtonContent"><span class="appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel exportLabel">Преглед на оценката</span></span>` @Dazed

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for using the text of the link?

```
<span class="appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel exportLabel">Преглед на оценката</span>


driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Преглед на оценката')]")).Click();
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kUvUjfJu this is the the full button lol. I missed some code.

Comment: try the above. I just used the name of the link based on your html.

Comment: sadly not working. I think it happens too fast and Google Forms disables the button, not too sure

Comment: run it in debug mode and step through it. that will help you determine if you need to add a wait for element in there.

Comment: omg my theory was right. tysm for helping me! It took 3 days to finally do it